# .net SQLclient SqlCommand parameters using positional not named

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

Strange issue here. I had a DBA change the order of some SQL Server stored procedure parameters and some statements are failing. However, these statements are coming from C# asp.net 4.0 calls through `SqlCcommand`. I read all over that `SqlCommand` uses named parameters by default. However, when I see the output in SQL Server profiler, it is using the wrong order for the first two params.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();

    var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MySp", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemId", itemItemId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastParm", "x");

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    bResult = true;
}
```

My stored procedure from profiler mixes the first two up:

```
exec usp_MySp @UserId='99903E7D-385B-4460-900F-6555756D275F',@ItemId='AAA0C211-C49C-43B3-B182-01A05D28087C',@lastParm='x'
```

I searched, is there something to making it be named vs positional? Thanks

Comment: Have you validated `userId` and `itemItemId`? If thats validated check the stored procedure.

Comment: I would run this statement `exec usp_MySp @UserId='99903E7D-385B-4460-900F-6555756D275F',@ItemId='AAA0C211-C49C-43B3-B182-01A05D28087C',@lastParm='x'` directly in SQL Server and see what happens.  AFAIK, procedure calls are only positional if you are using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I validated.  I run it switching them out and it works.  The values for the Guids are transposed.  The parameters are emitted in the order they are added to the parameters collection, but the value does not follow the right parameter.  I have found this to be the case for a lot of projects and wondered if something was up on my end.  Is it possible it's my connection string?    <add name="XXXDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=passwordxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: ok, big DERP from me on this one.  There was an overload of my function that was swapping them.  I hate working with GUIDS so hard to keep them straight.  Thank you!